# Vue3-carousel vertical (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, vue3-carousel

Hi im trying to create carousel vertical. As of now its horizontal. been trying to make it vertical but no work. Can i ask for help how to do it? really appreciate it.

This is the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-carousel-example-01-02j7p?file=/src/components/Carousel.vue

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not straight forward to make it vertical but does this project look like what you want to do?

https://github.com/jiaochunxiao/vue-vertical-gallery

with the [demo](https://jiaochunxiao.github.io/vue-vertical-gallery/)

If you want something vertical, I would start from this component and modify it as I see fit.